# While loop Time complexity

Tags: algorithm, while-loop, time-complexity

I have an algorithm exam.. and am a bit not great in the loops time complexity :s I just started to get the basics of it..

I have this while loop

```
i=2
while (i<n)
{
   i=i*i
   x=x+1
}
```

I believe that the solution must be like:
(i) will run from 2 to 2<sup>k</sup> where k = 2<sup>i</sup>

every time it execute the statement 1 time..

so 1+1+1+.. , this means 1*2<sup>k</sup>

and from here I can't continue..

the second question guys.. please recommend a site or sth that I can practice some more of these.. searched but didn't find :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop runs as long as the `i` is less than `n`. In other words, you need to find `k` such that 2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup> < n. ==> k = log<sub>2</sub>log<sub>2</sub>n. So the loop iterates for log<sub>2</sub>log<sub>2</sub>n times and at each iteration it performs 2 operations (multiplication and addition) - these operations take `O(1)` time.

==> The time to execute the loop is equal to log<sub>2</sub>log<sub>2</sub>n * O(1) ==> total complexity is `O(loglogn)`.

Comment: Thats What i though.. but wasn't sure about.. 

Thanks :)

Comment: If `n=2^64` => `O(lgn) = 64`; however loop executes only 6 times.

Comment: @icepack so its log^2 or log(logn)?? the second one ryt??

Comment: Yes (it would've been `logn` if power of `i` in each iteration was multiplied by constant)